# Express $\int \sin x ^3 \mathrm{d}x$ as a power series.

Tags: calculus, integration, power-series

how do you write this formula in power series?
A power series about a, or just power series, is any series that can be written in the form,$$ \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}c_n(x−a)^n$$
where a and $c_n$ are numbers. The $c_n$'s are often called the coefficients of the series. The first thing to notice about a power series is that it is a function of $x$.

Comment: Do you know the power series of $\sin(x)$?

Comment: @Arthur you mean taylor series expansion of sin?

Comment: If you want me to mean that, then sure. Yeah. It's just another way of saying $a = 0$.

Comment: ah, thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that$$\sin x=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}x^{2k+1}\implies \sin x^3=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}x^{6k+3}$$Thus,
\begin{align}
\int\sin x^3 dx&=\int \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}x^{6k+3} dx\\=&\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}\int x^{6k+3} dx\\=&\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(6k+4)(2k+1)!}x^{6k+4} +C
\end{align}

Comment: +C $\qquad \!\!\!\!$

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thanks! :)

Comment: thanks for the solution, much appreciated.